# How to edit a graph legend properly using ax

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have some code that outputs the following image:
[image]

I would like to edit the legend in the lower left graph. I would like to have it read:

H_0: "red star"

H_1: "green dot"

stacked on top of one another, where "red star" and "green dot" are replaced by the respective actual symbols (that are used in the graph). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# Define the function to plot
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))

# Generate data for the x, y, and z coordinates
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['black'])

# Create a 3D figure and a contour plot side by side
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)

# NEED A NAME FOR THIS SECTION
Zero_dim_births = np.array([-1, -.25, .75])
One_dim_births = np.array([-1,.75])

# Plot the surface on the left subplot
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')

i = 1 # intialize i
level_set_speed = .075 # how quickly the level sets expand
plane_speed = .05 # how quickly the plane moves up

for a in np.arange(-1,1.05,plane_speed): # controls the movement of the plane
    i += level_set_speed

    #Plot the plane moving up the surface on the left
    ax1.cla()
    plane = np.zeros_like(X)
    plane = np.zeros_like(X) + a
    ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')
    ax1.plot_wireframe(X, Y, plane, color='black')

    # Plot the contour on the right subplot
    contour_levels = np.arange(Z.min(), Z.min()+i, i/2)
    ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=contour_levels, cmap=cmap, extend='min')\
    
    # Plot the persistence diagram
    ax3.cla()
    input = np.arange(-1.1,1.1,.1)
    id_fun = input
    ax3.plot(input,id_fun, color = 'blue')
    ax3.axhline(y = a, color = 'black', linestyle = '-')

    for index in range(0,3):
        ax3.plot(Zero_dim_births[index], 1, marker = "o", markersize = 7, markeredgecolor = "green", markerfacecolor = "green")

    for index in range(0,2):
        ax3.plot(One_dim_births[index], 1,  marker = "*", markersize = 5, markeredgecolor = "red", markerfacecolor = "red")

    # Plot the barcodes
    ax4.cla()
    ax4.plot([-1,1], [1,1], color='green') # 0D component 1 
    ax4.plot([-1,1], [2,2], color='red') # 1D component 1
    ax4.plot([-.25,1], [3,3], color='green') # 0D component 2
    ax4.plot([.75,1], [4,4], color='green') # 0D component 3
    ax4.plot([.75,1], [5,5], color='red') # 1D component 4
    ax4.axvline(x = a, color = 'black', linestyle = '-')



    # Labels for all the plots
    # plot 1
    ax1.set_xlabel('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel('y')
    ax1.set_zlabel('z')
    ax1.set_title(r'$f(x, y) = sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))$')

    # plot 2
    ax2.set_title('Sublevel set filtration')


    ax3.set_xlabel('Birth (height)')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Death')
    ax3.set_title('Persistence Diagram')
    ax3.legend(['NEED TO EDIT'], loc='lower right')

    # plot 4
    ax4.set_xlabel('Persistence')
    ax4.set_ylabel('Components')
    ax4.set_yticks([])
    ax4.set_title('Barcodes')

    # snapshot
    plt.pause(.1)

# Show the plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Can anyone teach me how I might go about reworking that legend like I'd like to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use matplotlib lines's [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) to make a 'fake' line that you can then create a legend from.
A snippet of code that would do it:

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
# Create lines with markers
star = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='white', marker='*', markerfacecolor='r', markeredgecolor='r',ls='', label='H_0')
dot = mlines.Line2D([], [],  color='white', marker='o', markerfacecolor='g', markeredgecolor='g',ls='', label='H_1')
# Add legend
ax3.legend(handles=[star, dot], loc='lower right')
```

The `color='white'` and the `ls=''` are there so that only the marker (the red star, green dot) are shown in the legend without a line behind.

[image: figure with legend]

Here is the full code just in case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

# Define the function to plot
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))

# Generate data for the x, y, and z coordinates
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['black'])

# Create a 3D figure and a contour plot side by side
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)

# NEED A NAME FOR THIS SECTION
Zero_dim_births = np.array([-1, -.25, .75])
One_dim_births = np.array([-1,.75])

# Plot the surface on the left subplot
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')

i = 1 # intialize i
level_set_speed = .075 # how quickly the level sets expand
plane_speed = .05 # how quickly the plane moves up

for a in np.arange(-1,1.05,plane_speed): # controls the movement of the plane
    i += level_set_speed

    #Plot the plane moving up the surface on the left
    ax1.cla()
    plane = np.zeros_like(X)
    plane = np.zeros_like(X) + a
    ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')
    ax1.plot_wireframe(X, Y, plane, color='black')

    # Plot the contour on the right subplot
    contour_levels = np.arange(Z.min(), Z.min()+i, i/2)
    ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=contour_levels, cmap=cmap, extend='min') \
 \
    # Plot the persistence diagram
    ax3.cla()
    input = np.arange(-1.1,1.1,.1)
    id_fun = input
    ax3.plot(input,id_fun, color = 'blue')
    ax3.axhline(y = a, color = 'black', linestyle = '-')

    for index in range(0,3):
        ax3.plot(Zero_dim_births[index], 1, marker = "o", markersize = 7, markeredgecolor = "green",
                 markerfacecolor = "green", label='H_1')

    for index in range(0,2):
        ax3.plot(One_dim_births[index], 1,  marker = "*", markersize = 5, markeredgecolor = "red",
                 markerfacecolor = "red", label='H_0')

    # Plot the barcodes
    ax4.cla()
    ax4.plot([-1,1], [1,1], color='green') # 0D component 1
    ax4.plot([-1,1], [2,2], color='red') # 1D component 1
    ax4.plot([-.25,1], [3,3], color='green') # 0D component 2
    ax4.plot([.75,1], [4,4], color='green') # 0D component 3
    ax4.plot([.75,1], [5,5], color='red') # 1D component 4
    ax4.axvline(x = a, color = 'black', linestyle = '-')



    # Labels for all the plots
    # plot 1
    ax1.set_xlabel('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel('y')
    ax1.set_zlabel('z')
    ax1.set_title(r'$f(x, y) = sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))$')

    # plot 2
    ax2.set_title('Sublevel set filtration')

    ax3.set_xlabel('Birth (height)')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Death')
    ax3.set_title('Persistence Diagram')
    # Add legend
    star = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='white', marker='*', markerfacecolor='r', markeredgecolor='r',
                         ls='', label='H_0')
    dot = mlines.Line2D([], [],  color='white', marker='o', markerfacecolor='g', markeredgecolor='g',
                        ls='',  label='H_1')
    ax3.legend(handles=[star, dot], loc='lower right')

    # plot 4
    ax4.set_xlabel('Persistence')
    ax4.set_ylabel('Components')
    ax4.set_yticks([])
    ax4.set_title('Barcodes')

    # snapshot
    plt.pause(.1)

# Show the plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps, cheers!